# Alfresco JavaScript - How to get list of allowed values of a node property?

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I'm doing something like this:

```
document.properties["my:customProperty"] = getSomehowTheProperty(document);
```

`my:customProperty` is a string, which has some allowed values in the content model.

How can I get the allowed values from the content model, so that I don't have to store them in a JavaScript array inside the script?

Or how else can I check, that the function `getSomehowTheProperty` returned an allowed value?

I tried to wrap it with try-catch:

```
    try {
      document.properties["my:customProperty"] = getSomehowTheProperty(document);
      document.save();
    } catch (e) {
      document.properties["my:customProperty"] = "Default Value";
      document.save();
    }
```

But it looks like integrity is checked and th error is thrown at the end of executing the script, not inside the try block.

Googling "alfresco js allowed values of node properties" and similar queries gives me nothing.

Comment: Where is the JS running? Alfresco repo? Share tier? Web Browser?

Comment: The script is a file in the repo under `/Data Dictionary/Scripts/`. It is executed as a content rule action in some space, when new document is uploaded to the space. Sorry for not being clear enough at first and hope it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get that sort of information, you'll have to use the [DictionaryService](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/datamodel/org/alfresco/service/cmr/dictionary/DictionaryService.html) to get the [PropertyDefinition](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/datamodel/org/alfresco/service/cmr/dictionary/PropertyDefinition.html)

Off the top of my head, you'll want to do something like:

```
QName customPropertyQ = QName.createQName("my:customProperty", namespaceService);
PropertyDefinition customPropertyT = dictionaryService.getProperty(customPropertyQ);
List allowedValues = customPropertyT.getConstraints();
```

That'd be in Java, see [this blog post](http://blog.alfrescian.com/?p=202) for details on how to work with the DictionaryService from JavaScript